# Chaining bind() and unbind() event handlers

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain the logic of the chaining of this section

```
$("#name").unbind("focus").focus(function(){
    $("#name").unbind("blur").blur(function(){
```

of the following code? I can't access the `HTML`, but [here](http://www.codecademy.com/users/506200e0fe49de00020a0fab/projects/50b5505544cb452a19001070/) is the rendered web page. Also, is it possible to declare event handlers for the first time at the same time that you are unbinding them?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#name").unbind("focus").focus(function(){
        $("#name").unbind("blur").blur(function(){
            var name = $("input[name='name']").val().toString();
            console.log(name);
            if(name === ""){
                $("#nameError").css("display", "block");
            }
            $("#name").focus(function(){
                $("#nameError").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    });
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is broken.

The outer handler with its `.unbind('focus').focus()` chain is there to ensure that no other `focus` handler is registered.  It also ensures that no `blur` handler is even registered until the first time that element is hovered over, with a `.unbind` thrown in for extra safety.

However inside that handler, the inner `.focus` handler will be *re-registered **without** the safety-net every time the element sees a `.blur` event.*  The net result will be many duplicate handlers being registered on that element.

Comment: Yes, I think it's awful code as well, not just because the issue you found. it's using `unbind` when it should have used `one`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's what I get for trying to learn correct jQuery syntax by studying Codecademy user examples.    

1. So you're saying that you can attach `'focus()` to something like `.unbind('focus')`, even though the latter isn't an event (or is it?)?  
  
2. Could you explain why the inner `.focus` handler will be re-registered every time without the safety net if it's nested inside the other handlers?

Comment: @gdoron just tagging you in case you can answer my questions

Comment: @mrwnt10, what do you mean by "tagging" me?

Answer (score 2):

This is being used so any previous attached events handlers will be unattached.

This is commonly used with you use external libraries and plugins and you want to be sure to disable unwanted functionality.

<sub>Easiest way to know why it's done this way of couse is asking the guy who wrote this.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It's so that the bindings can be run multiple times without fear of duplication